# package javax.servlet.http does not exist error in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, classpath

I am getting this error when trying to compile my program.
I know this could be a duplicate but i could not understand the other answers given. Which file should I put on the class path and how do i do that? if indeed that is correct?

Comment: `servlet-api.jar`; how you add it to your class path depends, what have you tried? Where are you stuck? Generally, add the file to your project right-click and select "add to class path".

Comment: @ElliottFrisch so right click, properties, libraries, add jar?

Comment: then build again to recompile?

Comment: Depends. Do you have "Build Automatically" enabled? If not yes, if yes no.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch this is flipping dumb. on libraries it has servlet-api.jar there under C:\Users\Rich\Documents\Tomcat\lib. so how come it cant find it?

Comment: You should have never add this servlet-api.jar to your project. Add some server runtime to your Eclipse and then associate project with that runtime (as explained in the Kenster link). It will fix the issue you have.